# How to show WP addon installation path during installation?

Tags: plugins

I wonder how is it possible to see what is the addon installation path in ftp (folder name) during addon installation. I mean when we upload addon and then we have these texts saying that addon is being installed etc. When we have already installed an addon, and we try again to install it then we have information saying that it's not possible because addon already exists, and WP shows us a path. I would like to achieve something like that during installation. I need to know folder name after addon installation.

I know it's simple when we modify WP code, maybe we can even copy and paste already existing code which shows us a path to addon when try to install an already existing addon, but I'm not so good in php programming. Maybe there is .. an addon with such functionality? :)

EDIT:

Ok I found the file class-wp-upgrader.php and place where I should add code, it's line 800 and after `$this->skin->feedback( 'process_success' );` I added my code: `$this->skin->feedback( 'Source: ', $remote_destination );` but during installation I have text "Source: ", only, I don't understand why, in this file this value was defined at the top `$remote_destination = $wp_filesystem->find_folder( $local_destination );`